# How to put a bootstrap tab inside a fixed height container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a `bootstrap tab` control into a containing div with a fixed height. I have some details below the tab control and when I switch between tabs they jump up and down depending on the contents of each tab.  I want to avoid this so figured `Id` put the tab control inside a div with a fixed height, but I just cant it to work.

**Here is the HTML and CS:**

```css
@media (min-width: 768px){
    fixed-height-content {
      min-height: 400px;
      max-height: 400px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 fixed-height-content">
        <div role="tabpanel">
        tab stuff in here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    --- stuff here
    </div>
</div>
```

No matter what, the stuff underneath the `fixed height` div just moves up and down depending on the contents of each tab. I'm more of a developer than a CSS aficionado. So I'm finding it a difficult problem to solve, can anyone help me out ?

Comment: make a snipet code so we can see the problem

Comment: And the tabs and tab content too.